# send the percentage of charged by Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want Automatically send the percentage of charged by Bluetooth...
After connecting to another phone, I want to send the charge percentage automatically every 10 seconds to another phone.
please help me...thank
I used the following code but did not answer

```
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {


    Timer timerObj = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTaskObj = new TimerTask() {

      public void run() {

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth",
          "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTextViewPercentage.getText().toString());
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "country");

      }
    };
    timerObj.schedule(timerTaskObj, 0, 15000);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a bit too wide question, basically you have to listen for the charge percentage changes and also use Bluetooth or Bluetooth LE protocols in your own way to send the data over and listen to it in the other end... but best not to have any 10 second timer running, that's useless.

Comment: I edited. I used the code above but did not do it automatically

Comment: ((."mTextViewPercentage "===Charging number ))